# Spring Boot Asynchronous Request Processing Task Executor Configuration

Tags: spring-boot

From [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async) I have learned that, now we can return `Callable<T>` from any action method. And spring will execute this action in a separate thread with the help of a `TaskExecutor`. [This blog](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/10/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-making-a-controller-method-asynchronous/) only says that this `TaskExecutor` is configurable. But I did not find a way to configure this `TaskExecutor` in spring boot application. Can anyone help me?

My another question is should I worry about the configuration of this `TaskExecutor` like threadpool size, queue size etc?

As `pkoli` asked, here is my Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyWebApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyWebApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyWebApiApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found [answer here](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/async-config/)

> To use other implementation of TaskExecutor we can extend our configuration class from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter or we can use it as bean. For example in a boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AsyncConfigExample{
    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void configureAsyncSupport (AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
                ThreadPoolTaskExecutor t = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
                t.setCorePoolSize(10);
                t.setMaxPoolSize(100);
                t.setQueueCapacity(50);
                t.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
                t.setKeepAliveSeconds(120);
                t.initialize();
                configurer.setTaskExecutor(t);
            }
        };
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AsyncConfigExample.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a task executor simply create a bean as follows with the configuration that suits your requirement.

```
@Bean
public Executor asyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyThread-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Regarding the second part of your question, Yes the configuration needs to be provided keeping in mind your application.

Here's an explanation from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

> When a new task is submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable), and fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but this doesn't work. Spring boot uses another executor, with thread prefix name: "MvcAsync1". Should I have to do anything else?

Comment: Can you share your configuration here, it would help in answering the question. It seems that the default Task Executor provided by spring is being used, hence the thread is with prefix MvcAsync1.

Comment: Hey I did not use any configuration for task executor. There is actually nothing in my application.properties. I just copy your code and paste it in my Main class

Comment: Can you show the provide the code of your main class.

Comment: I have added my main class in question. please take a look