# How to assign Async executor for each controller

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

In our project we have some async requests in different `Controller`s which are run by different executors, some of which are shared between executors and some are specific to some executors.

What by mean by async request is this: the method returns `DeferredResult`, which is filled by task run by some executor.

Currently, some of them writing large amounts of data (which are not to be stored in RAM) directly into the `OutputStream` from the method parameters, which is something we want to prevent since it seems to lead to data corruption.

The one and only suitable way I've found to do this is to return `StreamingResponseBody` from controller's method. But in this case I cannot assign some specific executor, which is going to execute the tasks for the given executor. I can change the common executor by setting up my own `asyncBean`, but that only gives me one executor, while I want to have multiple executors for various tasks.

Comment: "It seems to lead to data corruption". Do you mean you don't understand why writing to the outputstream from async methods results in garbage?

Comment: @Kayaman I think I do. That's what I'm fixing right now. Although it works OK almost all the time except for the rush hours in the production server.

Comment: So are you working with async methods, async requests or both?

Comment: I would call that async requests: the controller method just returns `DeferredResult`, which is filled by task run by some executor

Comment: @Kayaman updated the post with the explanations on what I call async method (which of course is not method marked with @Async). If my terminology is not the one used in this case, I would love to be fixed.

Comment: An asynchronous request uses a `DeferredResult` or other similar type to free up a request thread. Asynchronous method uses `@Async` or other means to run a method asynchronously while still taking up the request thread. There's a significant difference.

Comment: @Kayaman OK, so apparently I have to call it asynchronous request.

Comment: @Kayaman I return `DeferredResult` from one of the methods called by controller method (some wrapper around my `Runnable`), but it is getting executed on the same HTTP thread.

Comment: Based on a quick glance it's not doable to give separate executors out of the box, but would probably be possible by extending `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. Don't know if that's worth going for though. Is there a reason you need multiple executors? Are you trying to avoid starvation or something?

Comment: @Kayaman In case one of the executors gets sluggish because of the 3rd party service, I don't want the others to become unusable. Also, we're planning on adding some monitoring on these executors, so it would be handy to have them working separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different executor for any action, you can do so by wrapping return callable within a `WebAsyncTask`

```
@Controller
public class MyWebController3 {

    @RequestMapping("/test3")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    WebAsyncTask<String> handleRequest (HttpServletRequest r) {
        System.out.println("asyncSupported: " + r.isAsyncSupported());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        Callable<String> callable = () -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return "WebAsyncTask test";
        };

        //Use any task executor here
        ConcurrentTaskExecutor t = new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(
                  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));

        return new WebAsyncTask<>(10000L, t, callable);
    }
}
```

For more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46317860/3708462) and [here](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/async-config/)

Comment: That's exactly what I explained in the post: in the first scenario I can't have more than one executor and in the second (and it's almost like we do it now) I have no right to write to the OutputStream, since it leads to data corruption.